# Return false if one element of array is not empty without use Iterators - Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a method where I receive an string array and I want to return false if one of array elements is false.

```
 myMethod(attrs: Array<String>) {
   for (const element of attrs) {
      if (!element) {
        return false;
      }
    }

    return true;
}
```

Is it possible to simplify this code?

Comment: `array.every(Boolean)`

Comment: `!array.some(Boolean)`

Comment: You should clarify what you're up to- title and question do not match

Comment: @ritaj could you please answer below in order to give you the correct answer?

Comment: There you go, thank you @Goldbones

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript [Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) has a method that checks if every item satisfies a predicate: [every](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every).

Example:

```
const arr = [1, 2, null];

const every = arr.every(item => item !== null); // Check if every item is not-null. This will be false
```

It can be shortened by casting an item to a boolean:

```
const every2 = arr.every(item => Boolean(item)); // This will give false for 0, null, undefined, etc.
```

And even shorter by just passing a Boolean constructor to a callback, which will pass items to it's constructor

```
const every2 = arr.every(Boolean);
```

Also check methods [find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) and [some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some).

Keep in mind this does use iterator, it's just that JS built-in functions do it *under the hood*.

Answer (score 1):

Try This:

```js
var attrs =[true,true,false];

var result = !attrs.some( elm => (elm === false) );
    
console.log(result);
```

Comment: OK about using ! some - but the argument should be array<string>

Comment: Use `JSON.parse()` for convert to array.